# Bare esp32 chip auto programming mode help

Tags: esp32, ttl

So I'm very much a newbie when it comes to using bare chips but since I'm trying to make a project which requires very small modules for wifi I'm stuck using a bare one. My question would be how to program the esp32 with a usb to ttl connector while also having an auto program circuit.
[image: what I have so far]
And here's the connector
[image: Here's the connector] I've also been browsing some other suggestions as well but I'm not quite sure if it'll apply to my connector and I'm quite new so I'm afraid I'll mess something up D:

By the way I noticed that my usb to ttl connector lacks a RTS pin is that a problem if I'm using an auto programmer?

It's part of my student project so I'm probably not gonna make custom PCBs. I'm just gonna solder stuff on to a prototype board.

Comment: Is your question how to make the physical connections? You need to be a bit careful with that particular USB-serial module, many were sold with a serious design error.

Comment: Find the schematics for the evaluation board, or some other (I know ESP provides these on their website).  Copy the programming hardware section.  You do not need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Yes mainly with how I should connect the multiple parts and wires. The connector itself is a mock one for the time being though as I'm actually using a type-C to ttl with a CH340e chip but the connections are similar. Right now I'm waiting for those to arrive.

Comment: @KyleB I did try looking at a few of them and some that were suggested in other threads as well and I'm going to try out some connections but if someone has a schematic and/or tips it would be nice.

Comment: Yes, you need either the RTS pin or button switches for EN and GPO0 to manually enter the download mode.

Comment: @Jens It seems like the chip does support it so I suppose I can just solder an extra connection on to it?

Comment: @ILFforever I did so, but it is hard to solder the QFN case

Comment: In both diagrams, you had the TTL TX and RX connect to the ESP32 wrongly. It needs to be TTL Tx -> ESP32 Rx, TTL Rx <- ESP32 Tx.

Comment: @hcheung Thanks for pointing that out I actually saw that error too and I did correct it in my later sketch.